# Prisma, How to query if string exist in another string

Tags: node.js, prisma

I am writing a prisma query but I need to know if a string exist in another string.

In prisma we can do this

```
  where: {
    id: { in: [22, 91, 14, 2, 5] },
  },
```

for arrays. but I want to be able to check if the property value exist in a string. Some thing like this

```
  where: {
    comment: { in: "some random string containing the value in comment" },
  },
```

So if `comment: 'the value'` it should match the query above. I can not find a sample of this kind of operation in the prisma doc.

I am looking for inverse of the string_contains function. basically the equivalent of this `SELECT * FROM table WHERE POSITION(comment IN "some random string containing the value in comment") > -1`

Answer (score 8):

I think what you are trying to do can be done by using prisma filtering and sorting function `contains`.

In your case, it should be looks like:

```
where: {
    comment: { contains: "the value" },
},
```

The above query will return you the records that contains `the value` on `comment` column.

You can have a look on this document [Prisma Filtering and sorting](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/filtering-and-sorting) and check out the part of **Filter on relations**

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use something like [string_contains](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-client-reference/#string_contains), which works like this:

```js
const getUsers = await prisma.user.findMany({
  where: {
    pets: {
      path: ['favorites', 'catBreed'],
      string_contains: 'Van',
    },
  },
})
```

Comment: I am looking for inverse string_contains function

Comment: I don't get your point from the way you've asked the question. You want to search for a specific text, that is inside a specific field in the database? "Give me documents where X field contains Y text", right?

Comment: An example will be if pets property in the model contain `ergent` I want to check if that property is a sub string in `emergency`. Is this clear.